# Nested lambda syntax and invocation?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I didn't know how to name the title, hopefully its correct...

I stumbled upon below lambda definition, and don't understand the syntax, wht is the meaning of `var = [=]` and `return [=]`?

also second question in `ConstexprLambda()` function below, why can't we must call `add(1, 2)` instead of `add(1, 2)()` why need for additional `()` while in the call to `identity(123)` the code makes not use of additional `()` ?

question(s) is put into comments of the code.

```
auto identity = [](int n) constexpr
{
    return n;
};

constexpr auto add = [](int x, int y)
{
    auto L = [=] // what is = [=]?
    {
        return x;
    };
    auto R = [=]
    {
        return y;
    };
    return [=] // what return [=] means here?
    {
        return L() + R();
    };
};

void ConstexprLambda()
{
    static_assert(identity(123) == 123);
    static_assert(add(1, 2)() == 3); // why can't we just add(1,2) like above?
}
```

The example is taken from [here](https://github.com/AnthonyCalandra/modern-cpp-features#new-rules-for-auto-deduction-from-braced-init-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### types

Let's start from the type

```
auto identity = [](int n) constexpr
{
    return n;
};
```

Here `identity` is a wrapper that stores a *callable* of type `lambda(int)`.
You can use std::function too:

```
std::function<int(int)> identity;
```

So `identity` take an `int` and return an `int` when you invoke it.

`add` on the other hand when invoked, takes two `int`s and returns a callable.

### extra () operator

You need to invoke `add(1, 2)` because the return type of `add` is a callable, otherwise you cannot do the `add(1, 2)() == 3` comparison because of type mismatch.

see the types live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/lyses9)

Comment: does that mean (in above add function) that `return [=]` and `auto T = [=] { }` are actually nested lambdas (lambda within lambda)?

Comment: @metablaster add is  a lambda that returns another lambda. [=] means capture by value.